# Transform mono on operations success

Tags: cloud-foundry, project-reactor

I'm dealing with the [Cloudfoundry Java client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) for the following use case:

- I perform a request that returns a `Mono<Void>`
- On success of this `Mono`, I want to perform an optional operation that returns a `Mono<String>`
- For deciding when to perform the second operation, I'm using  `filter`,  but it doesn't seem to work

So, it looks like this:

```
Mono<Void> service = createService();
Mono<String> serviceKey =  service.filter( x -> someBoolean)
   .map( x -> someKey)
   .flatMap(key ->  {
       Mono<String> key = serviceKey(key);
       return key;
     });

serviceKey.blockOptional() //returns Empty
```

My expectation would be that, when `service` succeeds and the `filter` operation is succesfull,  the second call `serviceKey` would happen. However, I saw with the debugger that the code inside `flatMap` nevers get executed. 
The `javadoc` for `Mono#filter` states:

> If this Mono is valued, test the result and replay it if predicate returns true. Otherwise complete without value.

Not sure how to understand that... Question is, how can I chain successful operations when the first one returns a `Mono<Void>`?
I just want to perform the second one when the first is succesful, and return an empty `Mono` when the filter predicates fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mono<Void>` means "Will either complete without value or error" because you can't instantiate `Void` type.

What you need is `then` operator, it ignores the previous result and "switches" the flow to the provided `Mono`.
There is also `thenMany` in case you need to "switch" it to `Flux`.